# Python conversion to ISO-8859-5

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I'm facing problems when trying to convert a UTF-8 file (containing Russian characters) into an ISO-8859-5 file: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to . Has anyone got an idea of what's wrong(?) given the following:

```
def convert():
    try:
        import codecs
        data = codecs.open('in.txt', 'r', 'utf-8').read()
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        sys.exit(1)

    f = open('out.txt', 'w')

    try:
        f.write(data.encode('iso-8859-5'))
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    finally:
        f.close()
```

"in.txt":
ё!—№%«»(эюпоиуыяафйклж;нцхз

Comment: I recommend using the with statement instead of try-except and try-except-finally. Not that this answers your question, of course.

Comment: @Devin Jeanpierre: that obviously assuming Python 2.6+ or 2.5 with `from future import with_statement`.

Comment: This is at least 2.5, since try...except...finally didn't work before then.

Answer (score 2):

feff is a [Byte-Order-Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character. ISO-8859-5 won't have any representation for it.

You'll need to strip it off your `data` variable before encoding it into ISO-8859-5.

Comment: There's a codec to do it for you, so stripping it manually probably isn't the best of ideas. See: utf-8-sig .

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Python have the `utf-8-sig` codec that will automatically strip the BOM off a UTF-8-encoded string or file when reading it:

```
>>> print '\xef\xbb\xbf\xe3\x81\x82'.decode('utf-8-sig')
あ
```